# Can't read an .RData fileInput

Tags: r, shiny

I want to import a .RData file with fileInput but It doesn't work, I have this error message :

> Error in my.data$TYPE_DE_TERMINAL :    $ operator is invalid for
>   atomic vectors

```
 dt <- reactive({

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

   load(inFile$datapath)
  })






  GetData <- reactive({
    my.data <- dt()
```

When I try my application with a .RData imported manually it works well (I remplaced **dt()** directly with a dataframe in my directory) ...

Comment: up !
I am sure that the problem come from load command, but I coudn't solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following example solves the problem. It allows you to upload all `.RData` files.

Thanks to @Spacedman for pointing me to a better approach of loading the data:
Load the file into a new environment and get it from there.

For the matter of the example being "standalone" I inserted the top section that stores two vectors to your disk in order to load and plot them later.

```
library(shiny)

# Define two datasets and store them to disk
x <- rnorm(100)
save(x, file = "x.RData")
rm(x)
y <- rnorm(100, mean = 2)
save(y, file = "y.RData")
rm(y)

# Define UI
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(".RData File Upload Test"),
  mainPanel(
    fileInput("file", label = ""),
    actionButton(inputId="plot","Plot"),
    plotOutput("hist"))
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$plot,{
    if ( is.null(input$file)) return(NULL)
    inFile <- isolate({input$file })
    file <- inFile$datapath
    # load the file into new environment and get it from there
    e = new.env()
    name <- load(file, envir = e)
    data <- e[[name]]

    # Plot the data
    output$hist <- renderPlot({
      hist(data)
    })
  })
})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Note that will break if the name of the thing loaded when doing `data=load(file)` is itself `data`, because the assignment to `data` will overwrite the `data` created by the `load`. Alternative is to load to a new environment; `e=new.env() ; load(file, env=e); e[["data"]]` to get `data` from the saved file. Also works if the `.Data` has more than one object.

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks for pointing this out and make me learn something! :) I improved my answer according to your comment.

Comment: This solutions works well with `.RData` containing only one object as in the `x.RData` and `y.RData` examples but fail with `.RData` containing multiple objects. Any quick fix or should I open a new question?