# Read and Use Several Objects in an .RData fileInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to access and use several objects from an uploaded `.Rdata` file by a Shiny App user.
It is possible by a simple call a `load()` in the `global.R` to access several objects stored in a `.Rdata` but I can't figure out how to access and use these when the `.Rdata` file is uploaded.

A reproducible example that mimics [this related question where the `.Rdata` file contains only one object.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894780/cant-read-an-rdata-fileinput)

```
library(shiny)

# Define several objects and store them to disk
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(200)
z <- "some text for the title of the plot"

save(x, file = "x.RData")
save(x, y, z, file = "xyz.RData")
rm(x, y, z)


# Define UI
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(".RData File Upload Test"),
  mainPanel(
    fileInput("file", label = ""),
    actionButton(inputId="plot","Plot"),
    plotOutput("hist"))
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$plot,{
    if ( is.null(input$file)) return(NULL)
    inFile <- isolate({input$file })
    file <- inFile$datapath
    # load the file into new environment and get it from there
    e = new.env()
    name <- load(file, envir = e)
    data <- e[[name]]

    # Plot the data
    output$hist <- renderPlot({
      hist(data)
    })
  })
})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This works when uploading `x.RData` but not with `xyz.RData` that gives the following error message:

```
Warning: Error in [[: wrong arguments for subsetting an environment
Stack trace (innermost first):
    65: observeEventHandler [/Users/.../Desktop/app.R#31]
     1: runApp
```

Ideally, since the three different objects in the `.RData` will be reused, I am looking for a solution that would create reactive elements `x()`, `y()`, `z()` that could be reused across several `renderXXX()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works:

```
library(shiny)

# Define several objects and store them to disk
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(200)
z <- "some text for the title of the plot"

save(x, file = "x.RData")
save(x, y, z, file = "xyz.RData")
rm(x, y, z)


# Define UI
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(".RData File Upload Test"),
  mainPanel(
    fileInput("file", label = ""),
    actionButton(inputId="plot","Plot"),
    tableOutput("contents"),
    plotOutput("hist"))
)
)

# Define server logic
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$plot,{
    if ( is.null(input$file)) return(NULL)
    inFile <- isolate({input$file })
    file <- inFile$datapath
    load(file, envir = .GlobalEnv)

    # Plot the data
    output$hist <- renderPlot({
      plot(x,y[1:100],main=z)
    })
  })
})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Produces the plot like:

[image]