# Reload fileInput when actionButton is clicked

Tags: r, shiny

I wrote a Shiny app that loads several user-defined `csv` files as fileInput. The app is designed to plot data from a running measurement and new datapoints are written to the input files about every five minutes. I want to be able to reload all inputs by clicking on an actionButton.

I tried to define the function reading the `.csv` as `eventReactive`:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton(inputId = "update", label = "Reload input files"),
  fileInput(inputId = "file", label = "Choose file"),
  textOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- eventReactive(input$update, {
    mydata <- read.delim(input$file$datapath)
    return(nrow(mydata))
    })
  output$test <- renderText(print(data()))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I choose an input file and click the action button, the output is correctly rendered. If I now open the csv file, add additional rows and click the action button again, the output is not updated.

Comment: The problem is that input$file$datapath links to a temp file which is created when uploading your file. So pressing the update button will read in the temp file again, but this file hasn't changed unlike your original file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945833/getting-file-path-from-shiny-ui-not-just-directory-using-browse-button-without) I was able to create a workaround for you problem. 
As I pointed out in my comment above, the reason why it is not possible to update `fileInput` with an action button is that, apparently, `fileInput` creates a temporary file in a temporary directory and the `Input$file$datapth` links to this temporary file. So you can reload the file with using the action button as often as you like, changes to the orignial file will not be reflected, since the link is pointing to the temporary file. I really don't know why `inputFile` works with temp files, but using the `shinyFiles` packages, you can build a workaround. You have one button which gets the real link to your file and load the data in and another button to reload the data. Pressing the load button will reload the original data and all changes to it will be reflected.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)


ui <- fluidPage(
    shinyFilesButton("GetFile", "Choose a file" ,
                     title = "Please select a file:", multiple = FALSE,
                     buttonType = "default", class = NULL),

    actionButton(inputId = "reload", label = "Reload data"),

    tableOutput("test")     
)


server <- function(input,output,session){

    volumes <- getVolumes()

    v = reactiveValues(path = NULL)

    observe({
        shinyFileChoose(input, "GetFile", roots = volumes, session = session)

        if (!is.null(input$GetFile)) {
            file_selected <- parseFilePaths(volumes, input$GetFile)
            v$path <- as.character(file_selected$datapath)
            req(v$path)
            v$data <- read.csv(v$path)
        }
    })

    observeEvent(input$reload, {
        req(v$path)
        v$data <- read.csv(v$path)

    })

    output$test <- renderTable({
        print(v$path)
        if (is.null(v$data)) return()
        v$data
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

**Update**

It is also possible to combine this approach with `reactiveFileReader`, see example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)


ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyFilesButton("GetFile", "Choose a file" ,
                   title = "Please select a file:", multiple = FALSE,
                   buttonType = "default", class = NULL),


  tableOutput("test")     
)


server <- function(input,output,session){

  volumes <- getVolumes()

  v = reactiveValues(path = NULL)

  observe({

    shinyFileChoose(input, "GetFile", roots = volumes, session = session)

      req(input$GetFile)
      file_selected <- parseFilePaths(volumes, input$GetFile)
      v$path <- as.character(file_selected$datapath)
      req(v$path)
      v$data <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session, filePath = v$path, readFun = read.csv, sep = ";")

  })


  output$test <- renderTable({
    print(v$path)
    req(v$data)
    v$data()

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working perfectly! However, in the meantime I came across the reactiveFileInput function, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021237/r-shiny-reloading-data-with-fileinput). Actually, this would be even better then reloading on a click event. I simply tried to replace your line `v$data <- read.csv(v$path)` by `v$data <- reactiveFileReader(intervalMillis = 60000, session = session, filePath = v$path, readFunc = read.csv)`, but it throws the `Error: cannot coerce class "c("reactiveExpr", "reactive")" to a data.frame`. Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: I was about to suggest reactiveFileReader when answering, but encountered the same error. I will have a look at it in the next couple of days.

Comment: By the way: do I have to mark my own question as a duplicate of the older [question I linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28021237/r-shiny-reloading-data-with-fileinput)? I guess it is a duplicate, but the first question was not answered sufficiently.

Comment: You do not need to flag your own question as duplicate, others might do that. Since the first question was not answered sufficiently, my take on it is that it does not qualify as a duplicate, at least not anymore.

Comment: I figured it out. You were pretty close. The trick is to call `v$data` as a reactive adding brackets at the end like `v$data()`. Then the error message doesn't show and the file gets updated automatically.